# resolving windows hostname

Tags: windows, hostname

my main host is windows and im running ubuntu on a virtual guest OS, im currently mounting a folder in windows and in ubuntu and i get this error:

in **/etc/fstab**

```
//Windows-PC/shared /home/user/shared`
----------------------------------------
mount -a
mount error: could not resolve address for Windows-PC: Unknown error
```

how do i resolve a windows hostname in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Install the following package:

`sudo apt-get install winbind`

Edit the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and add `wins` to the line

`hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

-->

`hosts:          files mdns4_minimal wins [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`

Now you should be able to ping your windows hosts using the netbios name.